# skylink can't dynamically change video soucre

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, skylink

I am trying to make a video app like google hangout with Skylink API. If there is only one peer in the room, the peer will be the fullscreen. If more peers are in the room, rest of peers will be listed in the right-bottom corner like google hangout.

When fullscreen peer left the room, one peer in the list will replace the fullscreen peer and rest of peers are still in the list.

My idea is when the fullscreen peer left, I use javascript to replace `<video>` of fullscreen video with one of videos in the list. However, when I did that, the fullscreen video is stuck. It looks like I stopped the stream or I can't simply show my peer's stream in another video tag.

The following is my javascript code, please look at function `skylink.on('peerJoined', function(peerId, peerInfo, isSelf)` and `removeFullscreenVideo(peerId)`:

```
const VIDEO_LIST_NAME = "video-list";

/*
 * Create a new Skylink object and subscribe events using the on() function.
 */
var skylink = new Skylink();

/*
 * Configures the Skylink console log level that would determine the type of 
 * console logs that would be printed in the Web console.
 */
skylink.setLogLevel(4);

/* flag to record if anyone is fullscreen */
var existFullscreen = false;
var idFullscreen = null;
var videoIDs = [];

/* peerJoined: informs you that a peer has joined the room and 
 * shares their peerID and peerInfo a with you.
 */
skylink.on('peerJoined', function(peerId, peerInfo, isSelf) {
  /* We already have a video element for our video and don't 
   * need to create a new one.
   */
   console.log("peerinfo:", peerInfo);
  if(isSelf) return; 

  if(!existFullscreen){
    // if no one is fullscreen, create fullscreen video.
    addFullscreenVideo(peerId);
  } else{
    // if it exists fullscreen, create smallscreen video.
    addSmallscreenVideo(peerId);
  }
});

/* incomingStream: This event is fired after peerJoined when SkylinkJS starts 
 * receiving the audio and video streams from that peer. 
 */
skylink.on('incomingStream', function(peerId, stream, isSelf) {
  if(isSelf) return;
  var vid = document.getElementById(peerId);
  attachMediaStream(vid, stream);
});

/* peerLeft: informs you that a peer has left the room. Ee look in the DOM
 * for the video element with the events peerId and remove it.
 */
skylink.on('peerLeft', function(peerId) {
  if(peerId === idFullscreen){
    removeFullscreenVideo(peerId);
  }else{
    removeVideosItem(peerId);
  }
});

/* mediaAccessSuccess: The user needs to authorize his browser to 
 * allow your website access to their camera, microphone or both.
 */
skylink.on('mediaAccessSuccess', function(stream) {
  var vid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
  attachMediaStream(vid, stream);
});

/* Helper functions */
/* get Room ID */
function getRoomId() {
  var roomId = document.cookie.match(/roomId=([a-z0-9-]{36})/);
  if(roomId) {
    return roomId[1];
  }
  else {
    roomId = skylink.generateUUID();
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30*24*60*60*1000));
    document.cookie = 'roomId=' + roomId + '; expires=' + date.toGMTString() + '; path=/';
    return roomId;
  }
};

function createVideo(peerId){
  /* create video tag: <video></video> */
  var vid = document.createElement('video');
  /* set attributes of video tage */ 
  vid.autoplay = true;
  vid.muted = true; // Added to avoid feedback when testing locally
  vid.id = peerId;
  return vid;
}

/* new fullscreen video */
function addFullscreenVideo(peerId){
  var vid = createVideo(peerId);
  var vidDiv = document.getElementById('vidDiv');
  vidDiv.insertBefore(vid, vidDiv.firstChild);
  vid.classList.add('fullscreen');
  idFullscreen = peerId;
  existFullscreen = true;
  videoIDs.push(peerId);
}

/* new small screnn video */
function addSmallscreenVideo(peerId){
  var vid = createVideo(peerId);
  var ul = document.getElementById(VIDEO_LIST_NAME);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(vid);
  li.id = VIDEO_LIST_NAME + peerId;
  vid.classList.add('smallscreen');
  videoIDs.push(peerId);
}

/* remove fullscreen video */
function removeFullscreenVideo(peerId){
  var index = videoIDs.indexOf(peerId);
  var vid = document.getElementById(peerId);
  videoIDs.splice(index, 1);
  // if there is still other peers in room, pick first item
  // in videos to be fullscreen,
  if(videoIDs.length != 0){
    var firstVideoId = videoIDs[0];
    var firstVideo = document.getElementById(firstVideoId);
    firstVideo.classList.remove('smallscreen');
    firstVideo.classList.add('fullscreen');
    var parent = vid.parentNode;
    vid.parentNode.replaceChild(firstVideo, vid);
    idFullscreen = firstVideoId;
  }
  else{
    existFullscreen = false;
    vid.parentNode.removeChild(vid);
  }
}

/* remove item from video list */
function removeVideosItem(peerId){
  var index = videoIDs.indexOf(peerId);
  var vid = document.getElementById(VIDEO_LIST_NAME + peerId);
  vid.parentNode.removeChild(vid);
  videoIDs.splice(index, 1);
}
```

How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try checking if the `<video>` element tag is playing? You can make it play all the time by setting the DOM attribute autoplay="true".

Comment: this is likely the solution, the video element needs to have its play state as true for the stream to render otherwise it will stay on the first recieved frame which is likely a black frame